# Chrome Remote Desktop accepts incoming requests but refuses outgoing ones

Tags: chrome-remote-desktop

This is going to be a very nuanced problem, so I apologize for all the details.

There are 3 networks, let's call them Home, Network A, and Network X.

Any computer on my Home network attempting to connect to sessions on Network A do not make it.

To be exact, the symptom is the computer on Network A prompts me for a pin number, I type it in, and then it just sits there perpetually loading (it never actually times out).

The very same computer, once connected to Network X (that is, any network other than the Home network) can connect with no issue.  All computers on Network A seem to block any requests from the Home Network, but with one weird exception: it'll work if the request comes from an android phone.  Using the remote desktop app on my phone, even while connected to my Home Network's wifi, I'm able to connect to any computer on Network A.

Meanwhile, any PC connected to Network A can connect to Home network no problem, and Home Network PCs can connect to PCs on any other network (Network X).

At this point, I don't know if it's a routing issue or what.

To summarize:

- PC connected to Home Network -> PC on Network A = doesn't work.
- Same PC connected to any other network -> PC on Network A = works.
- PC connected to Network A -> PC on Home Network = works.
- PC connected to Home Network -> PC on Network X = works.
- Android phone on Home network -> PC on Network A = works.

How can I get PC's on the Home network to connect to sessions on Network A?

Comment: Could you give us an indication of the network setup (routers/switches/hubs, wired/wifi etc)

Comment: Just a standard verizon fios router (model Fios-G1100)... the only thing probably adding to the complexity is a raspberry pi loaded with pihole acting as the router's DNS (and dhcp provider), but all requests with that are logged as forwarded.  I also tried the same setup without the pi connected and got the same results.

Comment: When you say Network A, B, X, etc are you talking different subnets? What IP ranges are you using, what are the subnet masks etc? What IP/subnet is the router on?

Comment: Home network is my personal home network... just a FIOS router.  Network X is a friend's personal home network (they use comcast), and I've also tested using my mobile hotspot - same results.  Network A is an office network, and while it's easy to assume the office is just blocking incoming requests, if that were the case then why is it only blocking incoming requests from my home network?  I tried changing my ip address too just in case that was the culprit, all to no avail.

Comment: As for subnet masks... uh (Edge tries to remember his networking classes from college... it hurt itself in its confusion).

My home network and my friend's network are class C networks (ie. 192.168.x.x type networks), my mobile network is likely a class A, and network A is most definitely a class A.

Comment: clarification - i tried changing my **external** ip address to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the answer is "hope Google fixes the problem."  Which I guess they did, because now I'm not having this problem anymore.